# How to keep macro looping on a specified worksheet even when I switch worksheets in the same workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to look for answers to this question but to no avail. I need this Macro to run on a specific worksheet called **General** on a specific workbook. The purpose, is to let the cell I24 be multiplied by 1.0003 every minute (which makes it a loop as far as I know). The below code only works when I have the **General** sheet opened. It stops looping when I switch to another worksheet.

Also, I want the macro to run automatically open opening the workbook, regardless of the General sheet being selected, so that I24 on the **General** sheet keeps getting multiplied without being redirected to the sheet. Just so you know, I have that cell referenced on various other sheets in the workbook, that is why I need the macro constantly running. Below is my code (It may not be at its optimum condition since I am very new to VBA):

```
Sub auto_open()

WshtNames = Array("General")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim num As Long

num = Sheets("General").Range("I24").Value
num = num * 1.0003
Range("I24").Value = num
 Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "auto_open"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thank you, I really appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analyzing your code and making some suggestions to improve and remove unnecessary code

1. Switching `Application.ScreenUpdating` doesn't make much sense in this specific case, because there is only one update in `Range("I24")`. Therefore no gain if you turn it off.
   There is only an advantage if you have many updates, so that they get performed all at once when switching `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`.
2. Use `Option Explicit`. This forces you to declare all your variables properly.
3. You set `WshtNames` but never use it, so this line can be removed.
4. Use `Worksheets` instead of `Sheets` unless you really need to use `Sheets` (`Sheets` also contains charts not only worksheets).
5. If `num` is `Long` then it can only contain integer/whole numbers. Therfore if you multiply `num = num * 1.0003` it will automatically cast into `Long` which is the same result as `num = num` and that means it doesn't change anything. You will need to use at least `Double` or `Decimal` here.
6. You didn't specify a worksheet for the `Range("I24").Value = num` so Excel assumes that the range is in the active sheet. This is why your code fails when you select another sheet. Never let VBA guess the worksheet always specify the correct one `Worksheets("General").Range("I24").Value = num`.

So all together we can change your code from …

```
Sub auto_open()
    WshtNames = Array("General") '(3) can be removed because WshtNames is never used
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False '(1) dosn't make much sense

    Dim num As Long '(5) wrong data type

    num = Sheets("General").Range("I24").Value '(4) use worksheets
    num = num * 1.0003 'see (5)
    Range("I24").Value = num '(6) Always specify a worksheet
     Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "auto_open"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Into this …

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub auto_open()
    Dim num As Double

    With Workheets("General") 'note we use a with statement to specify the sheet for the ranges (starting with a dot now!)
        num = .Range("I24").Value
        num = num * 1.0003
        .Range("I24").Value = num
    End With

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "auto_open"
End Sub
```

Or even shorter, because we don't need the `num` variable for that short calculation:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub auto_open()
    With Workheets("General") 'note we use a with statement to specify the sheet for the ranges (starting with a dot now!)
        .Range("I24").Value = .Range("I24").Value * 1.0003
    End With

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "auto_open"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This part of the code has wrong logic:

```
Dim num As Long
num = Sheets("General").Range("I24").Value
num = num * 1.0003
```

`Long` is a whole number by specification. If you multiply it by `1.0003` it is the same as if it is multiplied by `1`. Consider using `Double` instead.
Or `Decimal`, for better precision:

```
Dim num as Double
num = Sheets("General").Range("I24")
num = CDec(num * 1.0003)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Vityata but it actually did multiply just fine as it was. Like 10000 would become 10003 within a minute, but only when the sheet in question is open. Yet, when I have any other sheet open the macro stops running.

Comment: @mmok31 - `10000` would become `10003` within less than a second. However, this is not a good example. Try with `1` for a minute and see that it will not change at all.

Comment: @mmok31 your code fails if another sheet is active because in `Range("I24").Value = num` you didn't specify in which worksheet the range is, so VBA assumes the active sheet (which is the wrong one). Never let VBA guess the worksheet always specify one: `Worksheets("General").Range("I24").Value = num`.

Comment: @Peh Thank you Peh, your answer really worked. I took your advice too of cleaning up the VBA. I wish you put your code as an Answer so I can pick it as best answer.

Comment: @Vityata Yes I understand what you mean now. It will only multiply numbers starting 10000 but I get that it would otherwise not work for small integers.

Answer (score 0):

You must set your cell as a variable.

```
Dim myCell as Range
Set myCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("General").Range("I24")
```

and in the code:

```
myCell.Value = num
```

EDIT:

The whole code:

```
Sub auto_open()

    WshtNames = Array("General")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim myCell As Range
    Set myCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("General").Range("I24")

    myCell = myCell * 1.0003

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "auto_open"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I am sorry, but could you please post the entire code with edits you suggested? As for me the cell value became 0 upon running the code, which it shouldn't be.